# switch to different fragment based on state of data

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a fragment that loads a recycle list of data, but I want to it to go to a different fragment based on a few conditions:

> Switch to the error fragment if something went wrong

or

> Switch to an empty message fragment if nothing was found

I added the following code to achieve this but it's not working:

```
var errorFragment = new ErrorFragment();
var args = new Bundle();

args.PutString("ErrorMessage", "Error Occurred While Loading Data");
errorFragment.Arguments = args;

var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, errorFragment);
transaction.Commit();
```

it doesn't switch to the error fragment, it just continues with the original fragment and I get a blank screen.

The error fragment is not on the fragment I'm trying to manipulate, not sure if it needs to be.

Comment: To be very honest i am confused what exactly are you trying to achieve here because all i see is you trying to replace a fragment

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Why are you replacing a fragment? Are you implementing some kind of tabs or something?

Comment: in a way yes, I have a main view that has my navigation and what fragment shows up is determined by that, but in this case I'm looking to set a fragment based on the state of data so wherever the app is at doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very strange that you are having a problem. This might be a silly question, but have you checked that the fragment you are creating actually has any valid content that can be displayed and that its not a case of it actually displaying an empty (or non-visible) fragment?

You should really be using the support libraries and Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment and SupportFragmentManager (and off course AppCompatActivity). It is also often a good idea to keep a reference to the current fragment so you can access it contents from anywhere in its parent Activity.

Here's a method to replace Fragments:

```
protected void ReplaceFragment(global::Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, int fragmentTargetResId, bool addToBackstack = true, string tag = null)
{
    if (addToBackstack)
        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(fragmentTargetResId, fragment, tag).AddToBackStack(tag).Commit();
    else
        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(fragmentTargetResId, fragment, tag).Commit();
    SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
private global::Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment _currentFragment;

_currentFragment = new ErrorFragment();
ReplaceFragment(_currentFragment, Resource.Id.content_container, true, Resource.String.error.ToString());
```

You can then also retrieve a fragment from the back stack using this:

```
protected Fragment GetFragmentFromBackstack(string tag)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag)) return null;
    return SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

and can support back navigation of fragments with this:

```
// To support using the Fragment Backstack with back press
// Override OnBackPress and have it call this utility method
public void OnBackPressWithFragmentManagement()
{
    if (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 1)
    {
        // get the fragment to be popped
        SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate();
        var entry = SupportFragmentManager.GetBackStackEntryAt(SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount - 1);
        var frag = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(entry.Name);
        FragmentPoppedOnBack?.Invoke(null, frag);
    }
    else
    {
        if (SupportFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount == 1)
            SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate();
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when using SupportFragmentManager, I have the v4 support & fragment nuget package installed and it doesn't have that so I was using FragmentManager instead.

Comment: I already have a navigation setup in place, my issue is getting the error state to display when I try to replace the previous screen

Comment: With SupportFragmentManager, make sure you are using Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment. Because the class name is the same, if you have the Android.App namespace declared, it will default to the standard Fragment, not the support Fragment. Declaring using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment; will avoid the conflict.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to use SupportFragmentManager?

Comment: that it's not available

Comment: you were right about the check for content item, it was correctly replacing the fragment, I had something messed up that was causing it to show me a blank screen.